# How to order an array of 2-dimensional arrays based on y-coordinate

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have code that iterates over some interval in x and calculates the difference between the computed and the expected value, y.

```
def find_alpha_max():
    alpha=0
    alphamax=1
    alphamin=0
    n=10
    alphastep=(alphamax-alphamin)/n
    data= np.zeros([n,2])
    for i in range(1,len(data)):
        alpha=i*alphastep
        data[i,0] = alpha
        data[i,1] = abs(wavelen(alpha)-121)
    print(data)

def wavelen(alpha):
    val1,val2= energy_levels(alpha)
    transition= abs(val1-val2)
    wavelength=(h*c/abs(transition*(1e-19)))/(1e-9)
    return wavelength
```

This gives the output:

```
[[ 0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.1        61.37844557]
 [ 0.2        47.07247138]
 [ 0.3        33.72835938]
 [ 0.4        21.50950112]
 [ 0.5        10.44535124]
 [ 0.6         0.49201146]
 [ 0.7         8.43091667]
 [ 0.8        16.41859421]
 [ 0.9        23.56862328]]
```

What I want to be able to do is sort the order of the arrays based on their y-value, from smallest to largest, so that I can obtain an x-value that I can use for numerical minimisation. How do I do this?

Comment: Could you also include your input and output as an example?

Comment: Please provide some **minimal** example to illustrate.

Comment: your question is confusing. What do you mean by the 'y-coordinate of a 2d array'?

Comment: sorry I have edited. Hopefully that is clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Sorted(your_array, lambda your_array:your_array[i])
```

This will allow you to sort by the ith element of each one dimensional array within your larger array.